# Using mstscax to shadow a Remote Desktop session

Tags: activex, remote-desktop, rdp, mstsc

I've used the mstscax ActiveX control in a C# Winforms application in the past.
However I now could not figure out how to shadow an existing remote session. (equivalent to `mstsc.exe /shadow:<Session ID> /noConsentPrompt /v:<IP address>`)

Does anyone have information or an example?

If it is for some reason not possible to do, how can I use mstsc.exe with a rdp-file to have control over the settings like keyboard redirection etc. with shadow functionality?